# Conditionally Concatenate String

Tags: r, conditional-statements, string-concatenation

I have a dataframe with these 5 columns

```
val1 val2 val3 val4 val5
1    0    3    0    5
0    0    0    0    5
1    2    0    0    0
```

etc

I was trying to create a new columns with a conditional concatenate (the result must not concatenate zeros)

```
val6
1,3,5
5
1,2
```

etc.

Any idea?

Comment: Also maybe something like `gsub(",NA|NA,", "", do.call(paste, c(sep = ",", replace(df, df == 0, NA))))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a duplicate. However, couldn't find one so answering.

We can use `apply` row-wise and remove the elements with value 0 and paste the remaining values seperated by a comma.

```
df$val6 <- apply(df, 1, function(x) paste0(x[x!=0], collapse = ","))
df

#  val1 val2 val3 val4 val5  val6
#1    1    0    3    0    5 1,3,5
#2    0    0    0    0    5     5
#3    1    2    0    0    0   1,2
```

---

Another option could be using `by`

```
df$val6 <- by(df, 1:nrow(df), function(x) paste0(x[x!=0], collapse = ","))
```

Comment: `apply` on a data.frame is unfortunately quite inefficient, as the data gets converted into a matrix, requiring copying the entire data (different memory layout means it cannot share the representation).

Answer (score 0):

We can try with `replace` and `gsub`

```
gsub("NA\\s*|\\s*NA|NA+", "", do.call(paste,replace(df1, df1==0, NA)))
#[1] "1 3 5" "5"     "1 2"
```